# Page Refresh issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, log, page

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1095862068239

This issue shows when i am refreshing page so what will i do for this?

Comment: Delete your `var/generation` , `var/cache` folders and run `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy` command and check

Comment: May be permission issue as well for `var` folder. Go to `var\report` & read `1095862068239` & update question here

Comment: No it is Theme Problem

Answer (score 0):

If you put the following line at the top of the root .htaccess file, you'll see more information as to what the real error message is.

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

Otherwise, if you read the 1095862068239 file in var/report you'll also see the error that way too!